# Why ArrayList.trimToSize is not Called Automatically in ArrayList Class?

Tags: java, arraylist

It removes extra unused places in the list after calling `ArrayList.add()`

But why is it not called automatically in ArrayList class ?

Comment: Because then you have to enlarge the list again when you add another thing. ArrayList has amortized linear insertion time, because it doesn't have to resize the list every time you add to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an ArrayList is full when you add to it, the contents have to be copied into a new, larger array. Basically:

```
void add(Object newItem) {
  if (size == array.length) {
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newSize);
  }
  array[size++] = newItem;
}
```

The question is how you pick `newSize`: you can obviously pick a value *just* big enough to hold the new item, i.e.

```
newSize = size + 1;
```

but you have to copy `size` items into the new array.

If you added ten items into the `ArrayList` in this way, you'd copy 0 items, 1 item, 2 items, 3 items.... 9 items: the cost of adding in this way is quadratic.

Instead, adopt a different strategy: increase the size of the list by some multiplicative factor, e.g. 2:

```
* (List size initially 1)
* Add item 1
* Copy array into length-2 array
* Add item 2
* Copy array into length-4 array
* Add item 3
* Add item 4
* Copy array into length-8 array
* Add item 5
* Add item 6
* Add item 7
* Add item 8
* Copy array into length-16 array
* Add item 9
* Add item 10
```

So, as the array gets bigger, you do fewer copies. In fact, the maths works out that adding and resizing in this way is *linear*, rather than quadratic.

So, sure, you may end up with too large a backing array; when you've finished adding things to it, by all means, trim it to capacity. But it's more efficient time-wise *not* to trim it automatically.